# ¿Por qué no se guarda la edad en el archivo?

Tags: c, archivo

Realicé el siguiente ejercicio:

Crear un struct que almacene los siguientes datos de una persona: nombre, edad, ciudad de residencia. Pedir al usuario esos datos de una persona y guardarlos en un fichero llamado "gente.dat", usando "fwrite". Cerrar el fichero, volverlo a abrir para lectura y mostrar los datos que se habían guardado, que se deben leer con "fread".

Este es mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct datos
{
    char nombre[80];
    int edad;
    char cd_res[80];
}gente;

int main()
{
    char buffer[2048];
    FILE *archivo;
    archivo=fopen("gente2.dat", "wb");

    printf("Nombre: ");
    fgets(gente.nombre, sizeof(gente.nombre), stdin);

    printf("\nEdad: ");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    sscanf(buffer, "%d", &gente.edad);

    printf("\nCiudad de Referencia: ");
    fgets(gente.cd_res, sizeof(gente.cd_res), stdin);

    fwrite(&gente, sizeof(gente), 1, archivo);
    fclose(archivo);

    archivo=fopen("gente2.dat", "rb");
    if(fread(&gente, sizeof(gente), 1, archivo) == 1)
    {
        printf("%s %d %s\n", gente.nombre, gente.edad, gente.cd_res);
    }
    fclose(archivo);

    return 0;
}
```

Mi duda es que estoy haciendo mal, ya que al ejecutarlo aparece en pantalla la edad pero no la guarda en el archivo "gente.dat".

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Yo veo que lo guarda correctamente, obviamente en binario

Comment: A mi me lo guarda con el siguiente formato:
Fernando del Solar
                                                             ,   CDMX

Comment: Eso es imposible ya que cuando abres el archivo le estas indicando que sea en binario: "wb", write-binary